# Querying DBpedia for partial URI external link and official website matches

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I’m trying to retrieve Wikipedia pages based on the "official website" specified on them, but preferably without going and building a complete index of Wikipedia. If I query DBpedia using:

```
SELECT ?s WHERE {
   ?s foaf:homepage <http://www.nytimes.com>
}
```

I get the desired result, but there are several issues when trying to make this work in general:

1. `foaf:homepage` is mostly not set.
2. I couldn’t find a query-able propery that maps to "official website". In some cases, a query based on `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink` works, but of course in others you get a list of pages that happen to have this page as a link.
3. URLs take various forms - www.example.com, www.example.com/, www.example.com/index.html, etc. and I couldn't figure out an efficient way to query based on a regular expression or even on `STRSTARTS` - seems like it always involves producing a huge query result and then filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting on the fact that a lot of data in DBPedia is somewhat incomplete or poorly formatted. This is more or less unavoidable since its source material is the same way. For example, `foaf:homepage` is sometimes missing, but that is likely because in the source Wikipedia page that same info is missing. That being said, sometimes the crawling tools the DBPedia folks use misses a trick - if you think it's doing something wrong in converting Wikipedia data to RDF let them know directly and they can adjust their crawler.

Other than that, your question is a bit too broad to answer, really. `foaf:homepage` is the property used for the official website for a given topic. Where it's not set you simply don't know what the official site is. `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink` is a general link for any external resource that is referenced by the wiki article - so it's not just the official website.

As for the formatting - I have yet to see this, most links I encountered while browsing are fully formed URLs. If you want us to answer that you'll have to edit your question to include some concrete examples.

Comment: Thank you, I was assuming as much. I realize that `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink` does not guarantee that a page is the "official" homepage, but it is used in many cases where `foaf:homepage ` would have been appropriate. With regards to URL formatting, I do not mean that the URLs are ill-formatted, but that there is no way to predict whether the URL path with or without leading www. , with or without trailing /, with or without trailing index.html will be used, necessitating multiple queries.